# Uncommitted message not getting consumed again

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka listener to consumer messages. I have enabled Manual Acknowledgment. I have used Acknowledgment.acknowledge() method to commit the offset in case of success. In the case of an exception because of some API call failure, I haven't committed it.

I am a bit confused as the uncommitted message isn't getting consumed again unless I restart my application. I am new to kafka so I am sure I am missing something really elementary but search has been futile for this. 
Can someone please explain or point me to the right source where I can know what's wrong here?

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "temp_topic", groupId = "temp-consumer", containerFactory = "tempListenerContainerFactory")
public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord,
                                   Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    try {
        log.info("Consuming message : {} ", consumerRecord.value().toString());
        String message = consumerRecord.value().toString();
         objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
         Payload payload = objectMapper.readValue(message,Payload.class);
         tempService.processEvent(payload);
         log.info("Message: {} successfully consumed",message);
         acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while listening to kafka event: ", e);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The acknowledgement doesn't change the point at which your consumer actually read.
It only commits an offset to some storage (zookeeper or kafka topic with offsets) and not make any changes to offset tracked by consumer - for example you may not commit the current offset and override it by making ack on some next offset.

There are some ways that you can try to deal with failed messages:

1. You can be prepared for specific types of failure (e.g. timeout, deserialization error) - catch them inside listener and take right action (e.g. wait/retry or fail the application - depending on the nature of problem).
2. You can skip failed messages - catch errors inside listener, put them to some storage for failed messages (see Dead Letter Queue) and then make ack on them.

Answer (score 1):

I read a bit on it and found out a way to handle the failed messages. 
We make 3 topics

1. **Main topic**
2. **Side topic**
3. **Dead topic**

Idea is to consume the message from the main topic and if it fails because of any reason, push it to the side topic where it will retry it **n** number of times in **t** time intervals.

If it fails after all the retries in the side queue then push it to the dead topic where it will simply notify(using emails or any other service) about the failure.

I am not sure if this is the standard but this made the most sense out of everything I have read so far.

Please feel free to add or correct this if you can.